# forkbomb protection

Tags: linux, bash

Is possible to protect from forkbomb?

I do not want that user different from root can to kill my machine with a forkbomb

Comment: I pasted your title into Google; the first hit answers your question.

Comment: You are right. I have tried to search with google in my language only

Comment: @Marcelo: Please don't leave [such comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).

Comment: @Dennis: Why not? It's a basic question that has very good answers all over the web that aren't at all difficult to find.

Comment: @Marcelo: My comment has a link with a good discussion of the reasons. If nothing else, we want *this* to be the destination that Google leads to. Stack Exchange is not only about getting Person A's question answered; it's also about Persons B-ZZZ who come along after.

Comment: @Dennis: Unfortunately, links on SF are virtually invisible to me, so I didn't notice yours until you pointed it out. In short, I don't agree with the rationale. But I don't own stackexchange, so I'll respect this in future.

Comment: @Marcelo - we're here so that hopefully OUR answer will be the top answer on Google, and to ensure that our links do not suffer from link rot.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a user-specific process limit with `setrlimit()` on Linux systems. If you are using Ubuntu, for example, you can change the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu (or any other distro that has PAM module pam_limits enabled) you can limit the amount of processes a user can have. You can do this by editing **/etc/security/limits.conf**.

For example to limit the amount (20 procs as a maximum) of processes user "foo" and group "bar" you would add

```
foo    hard    nproc   20
@bar   hard    nproc   20
```

You can also do this by `ulimit` or `setrlimit`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers (vtorhonen and hrnt), that refer to system-wide limits, I add that under bash you can limit the number of processes using the builtin `ulimit`:

```
ulimit -u N
```

where `N` is the number of processes that can be spawned using this shell.

This might be effective for you because you place the limitation only for the malicious user.